# How to generate web picture gallery offline? (no php on server)

Tags: images, website

I've just attended a huge family gathering, and now an hour after getting home people are texting asking for the photos. The deal is that the images are like ~5mb a piece, so e-mailing people isn't an option.

I have access to a few web servers with plenty of space, but no php or any other server side scripting available. That's why I'm on the hunt for software(preferably opensource) that can generate the album offline, and than just share it for the world to see on my server. Of course I could do this manually, but there are to many images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about using [Picasa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picasa) and creating a web album (1GB limit)?

---

Anyway I suggest you to batch resize them (just for show'em), 5MB are definitely too much for a screen slideshow.

An excellent tool for do that is (IMO) [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) you can find plenty of howtos around, but here's a sample:

```
i=1
for f in *.jpg ; do
  n=`printf '%08d' $i`
  convert $f -thumbnail 1000x1000 out/p$n.jpg
  convert $f -thumbnail 150x150^ -gravity center -extent 150x150 out/_p$n.jpg
  i=$[i+1]
done
```

It creates both big pictures (max 1000x1000) and thumbnails (150x150) in the directory `./out/`. All that you have to do now is create an `index.html` file:

```
cd out/
for f in p* ; do
  echo "<a href='$f'><img src='_$f'></a>"
done > index.html
```

Here we go, just move the content of the `./out/` directory to somewhere in your server.

**Note:** It isn't the best solution to your problem, it's just a quick draft, but I think it's useful knowing such tools.

Answer (score 16):

You can use one of these (all open source):

- [Sigal](http://sigal.saimon.org/en/latest/) (my favorite, Python, [demo here](http://saimon.org/sigal-demo/colorbox/Climbing/))
- [PhotoFloat](http://www.zx2c4.com/projects/photofloat/) (lots of JavaScript, Python 2 (Java needed for building), [demo here](http://photos.jasondonenfeld.com/))
- [Cataract Gallery Generator](http://cgg.bzatek.net/) (pretty sleek design IMHO, coded in C (!), [demo here](http://foto.bzatek.net/))
- [jigl](http://xome.net/projects/jigl/) (no JavaScript, nice design, Perl, [demo here](http://xome.net/projects/jigl/demo2/))
- [BINS](http://bins.sautret.org/) (no JavaScript, Perl, dated, [demo here](http://dague.net/album/))
- [Photon](http://www.saillard.org/programs_and_patches/photon/) (dcraw support, Python, [demo here](http://www.saillard.org/programs_and_patches/photon/sample-gallery/) (90's design))
- [Imageindex](http://www.edwinh.org/imageindex/) (minimal, Perl, [demo here](http://www.edwinh.org/imageindex/sample/sample.html))
- [Lazygal](http://sousmonlit.dyndns.org/~niol/playa/oss/projects/lazygal/) (video support, Python, [demo here](http://sousmonlit.dyndns.org/album/))
- [igal2](http://igal.trexler.at/) (no scaling, no EXIF, pretty minimal, uses JavaScript only for slideshow, Perl, [demo here](http://igal.trexler.at/igal2-sample/))
- [Swiggle](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/l.ertl/swiggle/) (very minimal design, no JavaScript, written in C, [demo here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/l.ertl/gallery/))
- [llgal](http://home.gna.org/llgal/) (really resembles igal2, Perl, [demo here](http://bgoglin.free.fr/photos/200608-NordEstUSA/))
- [Curator](http://furius.ca/curator/) (Python 2, no current demo available, ['04 demo](http://curator.sourceforge.net/local/share/demo/dirindex.html))
- [Galrey](http://www.galrey.com/) (actually more like a PowerPoint emulator, [demo here](http://www.galrey.com/showme))

Some of these are mentioned in [this comparison](http://www.nico.schottelius.org/docs/static-image-gallery-generator-comparison/).

Comment: Finally found one properly maintained and with a following (Python-based): https://github.com/saimn/sigal

Comment: llgal is exactly what I was looking for!
you can even >> 
sudo apt-get install llgal

Comment: I was having a lot of issues trying to istall `Sigal` on Ubuntu 12.10. On the other hand `llgal` worked great.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Picasa to generate static html files for display on the web, just goto Folder->Export as html page.  From there you can choose a template and resize the images should you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

what about giving a try to [myphotoshare](https://github.com/paolobenve/myphotoshare)? it's a photofloat fork which uses a bit of php and permits to share content (original photofloat doesn't permit it).

Besides that it manages videos (original photofloat doesn't), permits sorting of albums and media, and has many customizations variables.