# Generate static gallery

Tags: linux, script, image-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate web picture gallery offline? (no php on server)](https://superuser.com/questions/190134/how-to-generate-web-picture-gallery-offline-no-php-on-server)

I need a (linux/shell) script which does the following:

It takes a folder full of jpg-files, generates thumbnails and previews (maybe using imagemagik's `convert`) and creates a html-page which includes all the thumbnails, opens a preview using something like [LightBox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) and links to the original size.

Does anyone know a script which does this? I could write one on my own, but it would save me some time.